# How to hide a button on Detail View conditionally in SugarCRM?

Tags: sugarcrm

**How to hide a button on Detail View conditionally in SugarCRM ?**

specific Detail :

Suppose in Account Module i Want to Hide Delete button conditionaly from DetailView page,
So where can i put condition for show/hide.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to modify this in /custom/modules/Account/metadata/detailviewdefs.php

Adding to this something like:

```
if (your condition) {
    unset($viewdefs['Accounts']['DetailView']['templateMeta']['form']['buttons'][2])
    //2 being the index of the DELETE button
}
```

You'll then need to run:
Admin -> Repair -> Quick Repair and Rebuild

Answer (score 1):

For SugarCRM Pro version

You should edit the **custom/modules/MODULE_NAME/metadata/detailviewdefs.php** file and change the **$viewdefs[$module_name]['DetailView']['templateMeta']['form']** array according to your needs. As by default this array is empty for almost all modules.

Example:

```
// Place this code on the end of a file.

// This line remove all buttons
$viewdefs[$module_name]['DetailView']['templateMeta']['form']['buttons'] = array();

// This will add some buttons according to your conditions:
if (condition for edit button = true)
    $viewdefs[$module_name]['DetailView']['templateMeta']['form']['buttons'][] = 'EDIT';
if (condition for duplicate button = true)
    $viewdefs[$module_name]['DetailView']['templateMeta']['form']['buttons'][] = 'DUPLICATE';
if (condition for delete button = true)
    $viewdefs[$module_name]['DetailView']['templateMeta']['form']['buttons'][] = 'DELETE';
```

Remember to run Admin -> Repair -> Quick Repair and Rebuild every time you change this file.